# UIAppearance Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance, xcode9-beta, swift4

After updating to Swift 4, I am getting a compiler error:

`Static member 'appearance' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'UIAppearance.Protocol'`

Here is my `viewWillAppear` method in my custom Tab Bar Controller subclass, I am setting the font of the item text.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // compiler error on line below
    UIAppearance.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], for: UIControlState.normal)
}
```

I'm having trouble fixing this, any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? Usually the appearance is set for a concrete UI class, e.g. `UIBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes ...`

Comment: I will provide more context in the question. This is a custom Tab bar controller class, I am changing the font of the bar items.

Comment: You need to call from UI class, not directly from `UIAppearance`.

Comment: It turned out that when updating code to Swift 4 from 3, Apple's helper introduced incorrect code.

Comment: You should report it at https://bugs.swift.org/ so nobody else has to deal with it :)

Comment: same ... also having the same problem

Answer (score 33):

Right - the current Swift 4 conversion tool (as of Xcode 9 Beta 4) gets a little carried away.

I was able to fix the problem quickly by reverting the `UIAppearance` conversion code, then updating the individual attributes.

For example, in Swift 3 I had:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
```

Xcode "helped" me out by changing it to:

```
UIAppearance.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
```

I was able to quiet the errors by half-reverting, to:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
```

Comment: Same here.  The migrator is changing the type to UIAppearance, instead of, say, UITabBarItem, UIImageView etc.

Comment: you can even omit the NSAttributedStringKey, swift can infer it